# How to compute the portfolio risk when weights are negative?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk, risk-management, covariance-matrix

In [QMiF (p. 239)](http://npu.edu.ua/!e-book/book/djvu/A/iif_kgpm_Carol_Quantitative_Methods_in_Finance.pdf.pdf) , the variance of a portfolio is defined as:

V(R) = w'Vw = w'DCDw = x'Cx

Does this formula hold if the weights are negative (i.e., short)?

For example, if I have a 5x5 covariance matrix of various futures contracts and my position is:

```
n_01: -100
n_02: 230
n_03: -140
n_04: -79
n_05: 290
```

Can I simply use the formula above and arrive at the portfolio risk if i take the square root of the variance equation above?

Comment: short answer: yes, it does.The covariance matrix should be positive definite, which means $x'Cx > 0$ when $x$ is not the zero vector.

Comment: Do I need to transform the positions into weights in any way? Or can I just plug them in as a vector = `[-100, 230, -140, -79, 290]?

Comment: you definitely need to scale your positions in some way. What typically makes sense is to express your $x$ as dollarwise proportions (not percents, not shares, not dollars).